# VLOOKUP returns values for some Lookup values but not others

Tags: microsoft-excel, vlookup

I'm not sure why VLOOKUP isn't returning the value.

I have confirmed that I'm using the VLOOKUP correctly and that both values 1 and 2 are a match (no leading/trailing values, etc).

Does anyone know what I could be doing wrong?

[image]

**Edit:**

I am using Microsoft 365

Vlookup Formula I am using:

```
=VLOOKUP(A3,J:K,2,0)
```

If I copy A3 into J3, I still get an error.

I believe this has something to do with the A3 values, not the vlookup formula and not the lookup value.

What I tried doing:

I tried Editing parts of A3 and then making J3 use a formula where `J3 = A3` and it worked, but it doesn't work if I use the original value of A3.

It's definitely something with the value, but what could it be?

When A3 is equal to this value:

> generate Rebate accruals, Project quotes, Marketing activities, Call
> lists for Sales; | create Ship&Debit conditions; | ensure correct
> SKU-customer-mapping (Backends, Standard Pricing, Excon Pricing, DND,
> HotSKU Management), includes creation of SAP

It works fine.

But when A3 is equal to this value:

> generate Rebate accruals, Project quotes, Marketing activities, Call
> lists for Sales; | create Ship&Debit conditions; | ensure correct
> SKU-customer-mapping (Backends, Standard Pricing, Excon Pricing, DND,
> HotSKU Management), includes creation of SAP upload templates from
> vendor approvals

It doesn't...maybe there is some sort of hidden character that I'm not aware of?

Comment: What version of Excel are you using? (not that it has any relevance, just asking for alternative formula). What is the formula you used?

Comment: Edited my original post.

Comment: We really need to see THE FORMULA.

Comment: Edited my original post again.

Comment: If you copy A3 to J3, do you still have an error?

Comment: Yes, I believe it has something to do with the values. I believe the formula and the lookup value are fine.

Comment: Edited original post for future reference, but what could be wrong with my value?

Comment: Figured it out, it was the character limit. Dammit.

Comment: Hi @LunchBox ,, it's working for me,,, what I did ,, Copied the TEXT ( A3,, what U have shown here ),,, using drag point increase the Cell HEIGHT,,, then hit the cell format,, Alignment,, clicked Merge & Wrap text option ,,, Ok,, then set Upper Left alignment,,, did the same for LOOKUP Range,, and applied the Formula ,,, is working !!

Comment: @LunchBox,, if U wish then I can upload the Answer with Screen Shot !!

Comment: Rajesh, I'd like to see what you did, can you post as an answer?

Answer (score 19):

[255 Character limit on VLOOKUP](https://superuser.com/questions/247427/255-character-limit-on-vlookup)

VLookup has a character limit, as soon as you go over 255 characters, it won't work for what you are trying to do.

If your lookup value has more than 255 characters, you will have to find another solution such as using the LEFT function, RIGHT, manually doing it, etc.

This was my problem.

**Edit:**

It seems this is another solution and the character limit isn't a problem:
[XLOOKUP](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/xlookup-function-b7fd680e-6d10-43e6-84f9-88eae8bf5929)

Comment: +1 For finding out what was the issue.

Comment: Beat me to it by 10 min. I run into this all the time when using a concatenated key field. Always have to wrap the source and lookup with `LEFT(...,255)` when doing indexing.

Comment: Once you start having to do work-arounds to Excel size limits, it's time to start question your decision to use Excel in the first place.

Comment: @Acccumulation No, that's the moment you start splitting things up or move to VBA. Sometimes Excel is still the best tool for the job. Not from a programming-perspective, but from a workplace-perspective.

Comment: @AlexM Doing calculations on the values that VLOOKUP is supposed to lookup in is screaming performance nightmare. - Not to mention unmaintainable.

Comment: then you use readxl with R

Comment: @I'mwithMonica I have to do something like this about a handful of times a month and I just create adhoc key fields on both ends and use those, so there aren't calculations inside the lookup (which is `INDEX MATCH` not `VLOOKUP` obviously). Anyway I'm only typically dealing with hundreds of records when doing _this_ kind of work so performance isn't high among my concerns

Comment: XLOOKUP seems to bypass the 255 limit without any problem and it's simple to use. I edited my answer to reflect this for everyone's sake in the future.

Comment: @AlexM For me it is usually a number of records in the high thousands and a lookup table out of my control, thus effectively immutable... ;)